# ELOQUENT - Calculating difference of datetimes in where-clause

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to check if the difference of two columns in my database is under a given amount of years - meaning DATETIME - BIRTHDATE < years

I have tried;

```
$result->where(date_diff((strtotime('datetime')-strtotime('student.birth'), '<', $request->search);
```

However, I get an error telling me that the;

> `return type of strtotime is a boolean`

Now I'm running out of ideas. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: for clarification:
**Value.php:**

```
public function student()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Student::class);
}
```

and **Student.php**

```
    public function values()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Value::class);
}
```

In the students table I saved:

```
$table->DateTime('birth');
```

In the values table it is:

```
$table->DateTime('datetime');
$table->unsignedBigInteger('student_id');
$table->foreign('student_id')->references('id')->on('students');
```

2nd edit:

Thanks to @motia, I've edited my code:

```
$age = $search->age;
```

This reads the age from the request, working perfectly fine.. but then..:

```
    $result = Value::query()
        ->whereHas('student', function($q) use($age) {
        $q->whereRaw(
            'TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, students.birth, values.datetime) < ?', [$age]
            );
        })
        ->get();
```

throws an error stating:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such function: TIMESTAMPDIFF (SQL: select * from "values" where exists (select * from "students" where "values"."student_id" = "students"."id" and TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, students.birth, datetime) < 19))

(19 was my example value for age)

Comment: Hi, can you tell me about the relationships of your models and how do you make the join between them? I will help you make the code as clean as possible.

Comment: @motia Hi there, thanks! I added the relationship info from the models, anything else that is helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are executing the condition to filter the table in your PHP code rather then building the query and let the database execute the SQL.

When querying you should think of building the correct SQL experession string.

For your case the condition expression you need can not be built with `query->where`, so you need to use `query->whereRaw`

```
Value::query()
// To execute relationships with Elquent use whereHas
// eloquent will generate a "WHERE ... EXISTS" sql expression
->whereHas('student', function ($query) use ($request) {
    // here the $query is executed on the relationship table

    // to get the difference in years use the SQL function TIMESTAMPDIFF
    // its 3rd arg should be the latest date to have positive difference
    $query->whereRaw(
      'TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, students.birth, values.datetime) < ?' , [$request->search]
    );
});
```

**EDIT**
The example abovee works only on mysql databases.
For SQLITE, the condition should be

```
'(JulianDay(values.datetime) - JulianDay(students.birth)) / 365.25 < ?'
```

And for PostgreSQL

```
'EXTRACT(YEAR from AGE(values.datetime, students.birth)) < ?'
```

Comment: Thanks! I have never used Model::query() before, and so I'm confused how it works - also didn't find a documentation.. the query now seems logical to me, but how do I execute it? New to Eloquent and SQL so I'm sorry if this is something obvious

Comment: The query in Model::query() is optional. Eloquent calls it implicitly really if you dont put it. It should be the same as your code.

Comment: Yo can get the result by calling ->get()

Comment: Thanks once again! I still seem to be doing something wrong... I updated the problem, would be so cool if you could help me out again!

Comment: @Felix, your database does not have TIMESTAMPDIFF function. what database are you using?

Comment: Oh no! I'm using SQLite, any problems with that one?

Comment: No, there is no problem with SQLite. Differnet databases have different available functions, so you may need to consider the difference in your code.

I will upadte the code with an example with SQLite.